# Inherting dojox.mobile.View and using _TemplatedMixin

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

Goal:
I want to create a dojo widget with a separate template that inherits dojox.mobile.View.

```
//Javascript
define([
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dijit/_TemplatedMixin", 
"dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
"dojo/text!./templates/myAppview.html",
"dojox/mobile", "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme", "dojox/mobile/compat",
"require",
"dojox/mobile/ListItem",
"dojox/mobile/Heading"],
function (declare, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template, mobile, deviceTheme, compat, require) {
    return declare("widgets.myApp.myAppView", [dojox.mobile.View, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
    templateString: template,
    widgetsInTemplate: true,
    widgetBase: require.toUrl("widgets/myApp/"),
    constructor: function (params) {
        params = params || {};
        console.log("constructor" + dojo.toJson(params));
    },
    startup: function () {
        this.inherited(arguments);
    },
    postCreate: function () {
        this.inherited(arguments);
    }
});
});
```

Template

```
<div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading" data-dojo-props="label: 'Templated View'">
    </div>
</div>
```

Usage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="globals.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require([
            "dojo/parser",
            "widgets/myApp/myAppView",
            "dojo/domReady",
            "dojox/mobile", "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme", "dojox/mobile/compat"
        ],
            function (parser, myApp, ready) {
                parser.parse();
                myApp = new widgets.myApp.myAppView();
                myApp.placeAt("kj");
                myApp.startup();
             });

    </script>

    <div id="kj">
    </div>

    <!--Crash-->
    <div data-dojo-type="widgets.myApp.myAppView">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I create the widget programmatically it starts up but it contains no template. If I create it as `<div data-dojo-type="widgets.myApp.myAppView">` it freezes.

If I simply inherit dojox.mobile.View and in postCreate add other widgets programmatically everything works. However, in order to keep structure an maintainability I really need to be able to both inherit dojox.mobile.View and be able to mixin a template.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the Dojo version you are using. The support for templating the View and other mobile widgets has been introduced in the recently released Dojo 1.9. So if you are using an older version, you would need to upgrade.

Useful resources available in 1.9:

- Reference documentation of the templating support in Dojo Mobile: [Templating mobile widgets](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/mobile/templating-mobile-widgets).
- For an example, you can also refer to dojox/mobile/tests/test_Templated-widgets.html ([live version](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/mobile/tests/test_Templated-widgets.html)).

Hope this helps,

Adrian

Comment: That did it, was stuck on 1.8 and moving to 1.9 did the trick. Thank you very much!